# How can url encoding be managed with ActiveResource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

Is there a way to manage URL encoding with ActiveResource? Specifically I am looking for a way to pass an email address as a parameter.

Currently my query fails as the `@` symbol gets URL encoded to `%40`, causing the lookup on the remote app to fail.

For example, the following query on the ActiveResource model `Person`…

```
Person.all(:from => :remote_find_by_email, :params => {:email => "john@example.com")
```

Produces the following URL

`http://example.com/people/remote_find_by_email.xml?email=john%40example.com`

Alternately, is there something the remote app should be doing to decode the parameter before performing the lookup?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [eks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526918/eks), I added the following method and before filter to the controller on the remote app:

```
before_filter :cgi_unescape_params, :only => [:remote_find_by_email]

private

  def cgi_unescape_params
    params.each { |k, v| params[k] = CGI.unescape(v) }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CGI::unescape on the remote end, that should take care of any % encoded value.  Cheers!